# Python SSH Commands

Tags: python

I have the following code :

```
def executeRemoteCommand(host, command):
    cmd = "ssh " + host + " \'" + command + "\'"
    print cmd
    subprocess.check_call(cmd)
```

When I run the command:

```
java -Xss515m -Xms48g -Xmx48g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -jar /local/experiments/helloworld/ro/server.jar /local/experiments/helloworld/ro/properties.json
```

using the function above, I get the following error

```
File "./util/ssh_util.py", line 85, in executeRemoteCommand
    subprocess.check_call(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 506, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

However, when I type in the call directly in the command line, it works fine.

```
ssh foo92 'java -Xss515m -Xms48g -Xmx48g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -jar /local/experiments/helloworld/ro/server.jar /local/experiments/helloworld/ro/properties.json'
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `shell=True` to execute that command through a shell:

```
subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Rather than push this through a shell, you *can* execute it directly if you pass in the arguments as a *list*; that way you don't have to worry about quoting the command either:

```
def executeRemoteCommand(host, command):
    subprocess.check_call(['ssh', host, command])
```

Note that both `host` and `command` here are *single arguments* passed to `ssh`. Normally, that is how the shell would pass the arguments into the `ssh` command, that's what the quoting around the `java ...` command line is *for*.

Comment: __But__ it may be significant to remember that `-jar /local/experiments/helloworld/ro/server.jar` is a single argument.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: not just `-jar ...`, the whole `java ...` command is a single argument *to the `ssh` command*.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: if you were to invoke `java` directly, then `-jar` and `/local/experiments/helloworld/ro/server.jar` would be *two* command line arguments; that is how the shell would pass it in as there is a space between the two strings. It is the `java` executable itself that then parses these arguments and pulls in the next string if there is a `-jar` string.